# sqlite explorer для android studio существует?

Tags: android-sqlite

sqlite explorer для android studio существует?
как то можно из Andriod studio к базе прицепится, таблички посмотреть, данные проверить?

Comment: эти изображения не относятся к сути вашего вопроса. Они указывают на препятствия процесса реализации инструкции указанной в моем ответе. Уточните над ними, что они не относятся к вопросу, а относятся скорее к ответу и могут(быть)/будут удалены. По моему так будет лучше

Comment: ок, жаль что не смог установить , но все равно большое спасибо Вам.

Comment: задайте отдельный вопрос с описанием проблемы с открытием базы данных в Device File Explorer. Наверняка поможет кто-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

1. `Android Studio -> File ->Settings -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories` введите `DataBase Navigator` ([ссылка](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CONTEST/Database+Navigator))
2. Нажмите `install`
3. Перезагрузите `Android Studio`
4. Откройте вкладку `Android Studio (3+) -> View -> Tool Windows -> Device File Explorer` ([ссылка](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer.html))
5. Выберите устройство в выпадающем списке
6. В структуре файлов найдите свой `<файл_базы_данных>.db` (Путь - `/data/data/<имя_вашего_пакета>/databases/<файл_базы_данных>.db`)
7. Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши и выберите `Save as`
8. В открывшемся окне скопируйте путь указанный по умолчанию и сохраните здесь же `<файл_базы_данных>.db`.
9. Откройте `Android Studio -> DB Navigator -> Settings...`
10. В окне (Вкладка `Connections`) нажмите кнопку `+` (*`New Connection`*)
11. Выберите `SQLite`
12. В вкладке `Database` введите название соединения (например, название устройства)
13. В поле `Database files` вставьте скопированный раннее путь
14. Нажмите рядом на кнопку с многоточием и в открытом окне выберите по указанному пути конкретный файл `<файл_базы_данных>.db` (*который мы сохранили на шаге 8*). Жмем `OK`
15. Нажмите чуть ниже кнопку `Test Connection`. Должно появиться уведомление об успешности соединения.
16. `View -> Tool Windows -> DB Browser`. Выбираете соединение, выпадает структура таблиц. Щелкните по ним и они откроются в отдельной вкладке.

---

**При изменении данных в базе**

1. В корне `DB Browser -> соединение` правой кнопкой мыши выберите `Disconect`.
2. В `Device File Explorer` сохраняете (`Save as`) свой `<файл_базы_данных>.db` по предложенному пути.
3. Далее `DB Browser -> соединение -> Connect`. Открываете обновленные таблицы (данные).

Comment: не могу выполнить пункт 6. пишет Run-as Package 'com.example.android.falen' is unknown

Comment: @user9232557 вы на эмуляторе или на устройстве, не самсунг? Беглый [поиск](https://www.google.ru/search?num=100&newwindow=1&ei=x4J1Wv36B4icgAad8LeoCA&q=%22Run-as+Package+%27com.example.android+is+unknown&oq=%22Run-as+Package+%27com.example.android+is+unknown&gs_l=psy-ab.12..33i22i29i30k1.19734.25046.0.27390.3.3.0.0.0.0.888.1056.0j1j6-1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.167....0.eXcNRKWKs-0) по этой ошибке указывает на проблемы с устройствами самсунг

Comment: @user9232557 перезагрузите студию, иногда помогает

Comment: @user9232557 можете попробовать Tools > Android > Android Device monitor > слева девайс > справа File explorer > также находим *.db > справа вверху иконка с красной стрелкой (налево) > сохраняете в нужном месте > в DB Navigator прописываете путь

Comment: Android Device monitor выдает ошибку, не запускается:(

Comment: студию перезапустил, и комп за одно.